# Android Nexus 4 KitKat

Tags: nexus-4, operating-system, 4.4-kitkat, nexus-5

I am looking to buy a nexus 4. I know that the new nexus 5 is coming out, and it is being released with Android KitKat installed. If I get a nexus 4 from a store such as best buy or another one, will my Nexus 4 come with Kitkat? If not, When is KitKat expected to be realised for the Nexus 4. If I am not in a rush to get a new phone, would it be better to by the Nexus 4 now, or the Nexus 5 in a few months?

Comment: Is there any reason why you want to buy the Nexus 4 from Best Buy as opposed to directly from the Google Play Store ($60 cheaper from Google)?

Comment: @dotVezz this would be because Google doesn't sell the nexus 4, now that there is the nexus 5

Comment: (Sorry for bombarding you with questions) Is there a particular reason you want a Nexus 4 instead of a Nexus 5? Also, you may want to look into the rumors of an LTE Nexus 4 re-release later this month.

Comment: Whether or not it would "be better" to buy it is entirely subjective, and not really something we can answer. The dupe has the only timelines publicly available.

Answer (score 0):

This question is both easy and difficult to answer because there's little official information about the rumored re-release. So everything I say concerning that should be considered an educated *guess*.

- If you buy a Nexus 4 right now, you'll have Android 4.3 (Jelly Bean).

  - Android 4.4 (Kit Kat) Will be an automatic Over-The-Air update sometime in the middle of November (So about a week or two).
- If, at any point, you buy a Nexus 4 from a retailer other than Google, it will most likely come with 4.3, and you will need to make sure it gets updated.
- If you buy the (Still rumored, not yet officially announced) re-release of the Nexus 4 later, it will most likely come preloaded with Android 4.4 *if you buy it from the Play Store*.